# Win 7 allowed REG commmand from command line from standard account

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry, standard-user

I only have a standard account (non-administrator) account on a `Win 7` machine.

In order to disable `Aero-Peek` I was able to successfully run the following from the command prompt:

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM /v EnableAeroPeek /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Why did it let me do that from a non-administrator account?  Shouldn't this sort of operation be restricted.  I could cause all sorts of havoc to the registry.

Comment: Just like files and directories the keys in the registry have permissions attached to them...

Comment: is the question answered?

Answer (score 0):

Your command shows that you set the setting for your current user (`HKCU` means `HKEY_ CURRENT_USER`). This is fine an requires no admn rights. Only if you would change system settings under `HKLM` (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`), you would need admin permissions.